# Is it possible to add the same product to WooCommerce cart twice with different prices?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

- If a customer orders 50 quantity, the price should be £5 each, and
  cart quantity is 50.
- If a customer orders 100 quantity, the price should be £5 each, and
  cart quantity is 100.

Same price, but the quantity increases in the cart, all as normal.

- If a customer then adds 1 more to their basket (51), that 1 should be £8.

**Cart**

Line Item 1 - **Product A**.
Qty 50
£5 each / £250 total.

Line Item 2 - **Product A**.
Qty 1
£8 each / £8 total.

**Cart TOTAL = £258**

*The same price but two different prices.

This is because I sell in pallet quantities, but if they request 1 more than a pallet can handle, the price for anything above goes back to regular pricing (I know, odd, not my decision).

Is this at all possible in WooCommerce without having to create technically different products such as a bundle version? Which contains 50, then the existing regular one which can be ordered individually etc.

Potentially using `woocommerce_add_cart_item_data` to add data to the line item as it's being added such as 'bundle version' or something maybe?

Comment: This is possible of course, mainly using `woocommerce_add_cart_item_data` and `woocommerce_before_calculate_totals` (to change the price when item is "packed" and make adjustments on unmatched quantity or quantity change)… You should also add 2 custom setting fields to admin product edit page, one for the "packed" discounted price and one for the "packed" quantity, to get something smooth and smart...